# Make options for mod flag more visible

Tags: feature-request, flags, chat

So, today a user posted Teamviewer details in chat. His TV credentials were deleted, but it starts [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/33405879#33405879). I thought "Well, that's problematic, I'll flag it so a mod can delete it, looks like the rest of the room is warning him against do that". Of course, I wasn't the only one with that thought process. This came to be kind of a problem.

In the chat room, when mousing over a message, you get nice little context buttons on the right hand side of the message; star, flag, and reply. You also get a drop down menu on the left hand side with similar options, all with fancy icons. Finally, there is a text element with the option to flag for mod attention without any decoration. This makes it visually less important, and it's only decoration that makes it act like a link is the use of a mouse pointer.

[image]

Being a typical user, I went for the most apparent flag icon, as it seemed appropriate. Others did the same, and our poor questioner got auto-banned for being spammy. Cue several mods coming in and a minor kerfuffle about this poor dude who got ban-hammered. He was fairly quickly unbanned, but the thing could have been avoided.

Ergo, I'd like to propose the following changes.

1.) Remove the flag icon from the toolstrip on the right hand side. For people who are actually interested in flagging a message, they'll find it in the drop down.

2.) Give "Flag for moderator attention" an icon and similar styling to "flag as spam/offensive". Apply a relevant explanatory tooltip to it to explain the difference.

[image]

I feel like this would clear up a minor interface issue. While I understand the purpose for auto-banning users if they are multi-flagged, but due to that functionality, the ability to flag and fact that there are multiple types of flags should be rescoped a bit.

Comment: I second this change(or something like it). I can only do so much as a RO to raise awareness about flag rules but I cannot stop users from picking a flag that is inappropriate. A UI change like this might help the user make the right choice.